# Recursive loop on a dictionary

Tags: python, jinja2

I have the following dictionary:

```py
{'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}
```

And the following Jinja2 template:

```
{% for key in dictionary recursive %}
                
    <li>{{ key }}
    {% if dictionary[key] %}
        <ul>{{ loop(dictionary[key]) }}</ul>
    {% endif %}
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

But Jinja2 always output:

```html
<ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <ul>
        <li>b</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

My understanding is that using `recursive`, it would show me the `c` element too, but it only works for a depth of two. Why is `dictionary` not changing to the `dictionary[key]` at every loop iteration ? The `dictionary` is always the original `dictionary`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, `dictionary` isn't being updated in the recursion calls, and the loop cannot continue because the keys aren't found.

A workaround to this problem is using just the variables assigned in the for loop. In the dictionary example, this means to iterate through the items of the dictionary instead of just the keys:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""                                                     
{%- for key, value in dictionary.items() recursive %}                       
  <li>{{ key }}                                                             
    {%- if value %}                                                         
      Recursive {{ key }}, {{value}}                                        
      <ul>{{ loop(value.items())}}</ul>                                     
    {%- endif %}                                                            
  </li>                                                                     
{%- endfor %}                                                               
""")

print template.render(dictionary={'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}})
```

The output of this script is:

```
<li>a
    Recursive a, {'b': {'c': {}}}
    <ul>
<li>b
    Recursive b, {'c': {}}
    <ul>
<li>c
</li></ul>
</li></ul>
</li>
```

where you can see that recursion on the `b` key works fine because both `key` and `value` are updated on each iteration of the loop (I added the "Recursive key, value" message to the template to make it clear).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
{% for key in dictionary recursive %}

    <li>{{ key }}
    {% if dictionary[key] %}
        <ul>{{ loop(dictionary[key].keys()) }}</ul>
    {% endif %}
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

I think you need to pass an iterable into the `loop()` construct.

Comment: The same problem continues =(