# html for jinja template from backend

Tags: django, jinja2

Question in [jinja2 recursive loop vs dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453007/jinja2-recursive-loop-vs-dictionary) introduces a way to handle jinja templates in backend. If I have the following in my django view-function:

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("""                                                     
{%- for key, value in dictionary.items() recursive %}                       
  <li>{{ key }}                                                             
    {%- if value %}                                                         
      Recursive {{ key }}, {{value}}                                        
      <ul>{{ loop(value.items())}}</ul>                                     
    {%- endif %}                                                            
  </li>                                                                     
{%- endfor %}                                                               
""")

return template.render(dictionary={'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}})
```

what kind of html will provide the following into my web-page:

a Recursive a, {'b': {'c': {}}}

b Recursive b, {'c': {}}
c

Comment: test it by yourself

Comment: I don't know how because I don't know what kind of HTML would print something into web-page

Comment: Got it, for instance this way: from django.http import HttpResponse ...  return HttpResponse(template.render(dictionary={'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}))